# Drop dropdownlist?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

> [dropdownlist](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dropdownlist):A drop down list is a list with predetermined options that expands when clicked to reveal the options available.

Do we have experts on drop-down lists?
Does this tag helps clarifying questions' scope?

I think no, so the tag should be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds more like something related specifically to UI design than something I'd consider appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a meta tag.

The few questions I've looked at all seem Excel related. Maybe some advice in the wiki to use [gui](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gui) instead would suffice?

Comment: When people ask about dropdown list they generally refer to the one available through [tag:data-validation], maybe we should redirect them there.

Comment: We probably need clear the existing list to make sure any referring to the GUI element rather than data validation are re-tagged appropriately.